# How do I connect to a VM using Remote Tools?

Tags: embedded, windows-embedded-compact

I'm using Compact 7 and try to follow the steps in a book called "Professional Windows Embedded Compact 7".  I managed all the exercises up to chapter 8 but now I'm stuck.

Chapter 9 is about Remote Tools.  I build and deployed the OS as described in the book and everything is working fine but when trying to connect remotely, it doesn't seem to work.  For example when using the "Remote File Viewer" from the "Tools\Remote Tools" menu, I select the target device from the "Select a Windows CE Device" menu and it shows the "Connecting to device" dialog but it stays there and never connects.

I also tried the Remote Profiling tool and other remote tools, they all failed to connect.  Is there anything that I'm doing wrong or does this mean that it is not possible to use Remote Tools for a Virtual PC?

Answer (score 0):

I found this Microsoft topic:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6012.how-to-use-the-remote-tools-framework-without-kitl-or-activesync-windows-embedded-compact-7.aspx

Hope this help you.

Thomas.